# Dynamic number allocation in twilio and business verification

Tags: node.js, express, dynamic, twilio, twilio-api

I am building an application in which I will assign a new number to every user of my application and I can assign it through the code:

```
client.incomingPhoneNumbers.create({phoneNumber: String(phoneNumber)})
```

But now I want if the user call on this number I will forward the call on the user's actual number. How can I do that? And then after that, I want to send a message to the person who called and also the user but if the number is of usa, I am having geo permission issue how can I turn that on dynamically and the last thing can I proceed with US A2P business verification is it only possible through the console or is there any way and if it is only possible through the console can you give me the architecture of how I can design my application should a buy bunch of numbers verify those numbers and then assign to the customer or how should I do that

```
app.get("/get-available-numbers", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const numbers = await client.availablePhoneNumbers("US").local.list({});
    res.send(numbers);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});

app.get("/buy-number", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { phoneNumber } = req.query;
    const number = await client.incomingPhoneNumbers.create({
      phoneNumber: String(phoneNumber),
      // forward to the following url
      voiceUrl: "http://localhost:5000/forward-call",
      smsUrl: "http://localhost:5000/send-sms",
    });
    res.send(number);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```